# passing arguments through links in rails, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question is part of a much bigger question I have regarding Ruby on Rails, i.e where and how does ruby meet rails? How do we interact between controller and views and models. But to be specific.

I have a link_to method where I call a custom method. How do I pass arguments to that method?

for example

```
    %td= link_to "Reject", toggle_field_admin_entry_path(photo, "foo")
```

so my understanding so far suggests 'photo' is the object that the action should act upon, but the 'argument' could be a value, so as to do something like this

```
def toggle_field(argument)
    if argument == "foo"
     do this to photo
    else
     do that to photo
    end    
  end
```

can we do this simply as a string? or does it have to be a hash? 
I have a basic understanding of ruby methods, but I am struggling to understand their relationship with views in rails.

If you require further clarification, please don't be snotty about it, I am trying to learn here. If you feel I am of topic I'll edit myanswer to be more on topic.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Comment: @xlembouras, yes yes i know, everyone posts this. thank you though, for the 123456789th time

Comment: don't get it wrong man. It is just that your question is about some really basic stuff of rails. IMO you will learn better and quicker through some guides than from questions on SO.

Comment: @xlembouras yeah you're right. Its on my bucket list. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params`:

in views:

```
link_to "Reject", toggle_field_admin_entry_path(photo, { params: { bar: "foo",
                                                                   baz: "wtf" } })
```

in action:

```
def toggle_field
  if params[:bar] == "foo"
   do this to photo
  elsif params[:baz] == "wtf"
   do that to photo
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Buy using better routing you can achieve this, example:

**routes.rb file**

```
get 'some_controller/toggle_field_action/:arg1/:arg2' => 'some_controller#toggle_field_action'), as:'toggle_field_admin_entry'
```

**View file**

```
 %td= link_to "Reject", toggle_field_admin_entry_path(photo, arg1: "test", arg2: "test2")
```

**You can receive in the controller action:**

```
params[:arg1]
params[:arg2]
```